# Skip to line number in Chrome Developer sources tab?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a quick way to skip to a specific line number in the sources tab on chrome developer.  I am using angularJs and the entire code base shows up in one file with all my own code at the end.  Trying to view errors in my js code, I get a line number like 78,112 and that's a lot of scrolling.  Just wondering if there is a way to jump to a line number in the UI that I haven't found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For windows, mac & linux use Ctrl + G.

Here's a list of all the handy shortcuts for chrome dev tools.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts

Comment: If that doesn't work (which it doesn't sometimes for reasons I don't get) you can also try command O and then type :123 to go to a line in the source code.